# Eclipse cannot run two java projects with self written module

Tags: java, eclipse, module

I have two projects. First exported module project ("prjuno"), second test ("prjTest") to work in Eclipse (version Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0) Build id: 20230309-1520, JDK 17.0.5).
I'm trying to call from (prjtest) a self written module (prjuno)

I created 2 maven eclipse projects where my Prjuno class is:

```
package sm.clagenna.prjuno;

public class PrimoProg {

  public void doTheJob() {
    System.out.println("PrjUno : PrimoProg.doTheJob()" );
  }
}
```

prjuno `module-info.java` is:

```
module prjuno {
  exports sm.clagenna.prjuno;
}
```

In my second project prjtest class is:

```
package sm.clagenna.prtest;
import sm.clagenna.prjuno.PrimoProg;

public class PrjTest {

  public void doTheTest() {
    System.out.println("I am in PrjTest");
    PrimoProg prog = new PrimoProg();
    prog.doTheJob();
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrjTest app = new PrjTest();
    app.doTheTest();
    System.out.println("End of my PrjTest");
  }
}
```

My prjTest `module-info.java` is:

```
module prjTest {
  requires prjuno;
}
```

I added in project prjTest `build path -> Java Build path -> Projects: modulepath=prjuno`

If I launch  PrjTest I get the error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module prjuno not found, required by prjTest
```

For the ease of test I've made 2 GitHub public projects ([prjtest](https://github.com/clagenna/prjTest.git)) and ([prjuno](https://github.com/clagenna/prjuno.git))

If I install my project "prjuno" on my maven repository and declare a dependency on it, everthing ok. But 2 bare eclipse projects no.

I traveled some aswers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295226/eclipse-cannot-find-module-even-the-module-path-is-explicitly-provided) one related to JavaFX) but didn't find the solution for a self written module project.

Any solution will be highly appreciated

Comment: not sure what is meant by "`modulepath=prjuno`" but in the run configuration of Eclipse, `Dependencies` tab, under `Modulepath Entries` there must be `prjuno` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiBK4.png)) - if that entry is missing, I get the same error.  || after removing all the resources and test folders from the source path (since not in Github) it seems to work: [console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8VWG.png)

Comment: Thanks! That done the trick! But it's waste of time to declare depedencies twice:1- java build path project modulePath, 2 - Run - Configurations - Dependencies. Anyway thank again